# Spark scala - Fetch Dataset column and convert to Seq

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, seq

I have a Dataset

```
case class MyDS ( id: Int, name: String )
```

I want to fetch all the names in a sequence without using collect.

I have gone through various posts and the only solution I found was with collect. Is there a better way to do it without using collect

Below is the code I ran which compiles but errors out due to memory

```
ds.collect().map(x => x.name)
```

I am new to Scala and thus some might see this question as silly but would much appreciate if there is something anyone can share without down voting this question

Comment: Why is it necessary to collect the data on the Driver? Is there a technical requirement that prevents you from working with the 'names' in a distributed fashion?

Answer (score 0):

```
.toLocalIterator().map(...).forEach(...add to Seq)
```

This will process the partitions 'one at a time' on the driver (vs placing entire RDD into driver memory). The memory required on the driver is equal to the size of the largest partition.

Test if the Seq will fit in driver memory:

```
.map(x => x.name).collect().toSeq()
```

This method will reduce the size of the RDD (and its partitions) before sending the data to the driver. If this causes the driver to run out of memory then the only option is to increase driver memory.

Notes here:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#collect
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#toLocalIterator